# Auto-detect the logout in browser tabs?

Tags: javascript, django, logout

I have multiple tabs opened of a website in a browser. My question is if I logout from one window "How do other windows will detect  that user has been logged out?" I am using python/django for development

The approach I am using is:

```
function user_checking(){

         $.ajax({
            url: /check_user_login,
            type: 'POST',

            success: function (data) {

            if (data['user_status'] == 'not_loggedin'){
            location.reload(); 
            }

            },
            error: function (data) {
            },

         }); //ajax end
    }

    var validateSession = setInterval(user_checking, 1000);
```

I am sending  user_checking() every second to check if the user is logged out or not. Is this the right approach ?

Comment: Could set a cookie and poll for the cookie value every 'x' seconds? I think cookies work across tabs in the same browser.

Comment: It means polling from the frontend is necessary ... there is no other way  .. right?

Comment: I'm sure there is 100 ways to do what you're asking, but this is just what came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a perfect use case for [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

> The WebSocket API is an advanced technology that makes it possible to
>   open a two-way interactive communication session between the user's
>   browser and a server. With this API, you can send messages to a server
>   and **receive event-driven responses without having to poll the server
>   for a reply**.

A you are using the Django framework, I suggest you to read this article:

https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django

If you don't want or can't use WebSocket technology, then I think your solution is not bad for a small web site.

A more lazy way could be to let the other tabs untouched until a request is made to the server. Then, the server would return a response telling that the user is disconnected.